# mssql, asp.net, I need to deliver table, without records associated with specific ID

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Imagine, that I need to retrieve all records excluding, those, that are associated 
with specific ID, for instance if you consider table below and chose RestaurantID 1, resulting table should not include rows, that contain CuisineID 3,4 and 7.

If RestaurantID is 6, then resulting table should return anything without CuisineID 1 and 8
and so on

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzUmV.png)

Kind regards
erwre

Comment: Let me google that for you.  "SQL Exclude ID"

Comment: @Seano666 I can't believe they banned comments that contain LMGTFY links.

Comment: You did not understand, I know how to exclude ID, what I need is a Table, that do not contain Cuisine ID values associated With specific RestaurantID. For instance if I heave RestaurantID 1, I need table, that do not have CuisineID 3 4 and 7

Comment: @user3588746 You're talking about creating tables for different filter instances, like on the fly?  That doesn't even make sense.  Sounds like you just need to make the right query.  Or create a stored procedure and pass the ID you want to use into it as a parameter.

Comment: @Seano666 , it makes sense in project, that I am doing, and I know that I just need right query, this is why I posted this question, so more knowledgeable people than me, who know the answer can help me.

Answer (score 0):

if you do a subselect with your query, you can get a list of which CuisineID's to exclude using the NOT IN clause.

```
select
t.*
from
mytable t 
where
t.CuisineID NOT IN 
(
 select
 t2.CuisineID
 from
 mytable t2
 where
 t2.ID = @YOUR_RESTAURANT_ID
)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your answers. Refer to [answer].